# Why does'nt my pictures stay in my container?

Tags: html, css, width, space

I have run into a problem, my pictures, will not stay inside my wrapper.
I cant move with my boxes, or edit my css for my image divs.
Anyone who got an idea how to crack this case?
I really hope you guys can understand me and help me find a solution to my problem.

I will try and provide any more necessary information if needed.

```css
#content{
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: oblique;
  margin: 30px 0;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#imagediv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 325px;  
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

#imagediv2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="logo">
    <h1>My Web Portfolio</a></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/me.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    <h3>Check out my slider with my templates</h3>

    <div id="imagediv">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">
    </div>
    <div id="imagediv2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">
    </div>
    <div id="imagediv3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: The "Image divs" I want them moved into the center of my page, but I am unable to move them around, I am pulling my hairs out atm.

Comment: Post a screenshot of how they look now and how do you want them to look. You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/m4gjwsx5/ ?

Comment: Excactly, but with the boxes next to each other.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/m4gjwsx5/4/?

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/162/

HTML

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="logo">
    <h1>My Web Portfolio</a></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/me.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    <h3>Check out my slider with my templates</h3>

    <div class="image-divs">
     <div id="imagediv">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">
    </div>
    <div id="imagediv2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">
    </div>
    <div id="imagediv3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content{
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: oblique;
  margin: 30px 0;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#imagediv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

#imagediv2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.image-divs {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.image-divs div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made you a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/m4gjwsx5/4/

```css
#content{
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: oblique;
  margin: 30px 0;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.custom_img{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="logo">
    <h1>My Web Portfolio</a></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/me.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    <h3>Check out my slider with my templates</h3>

    <div id="imagediv" class='custom_img'>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">
    </div>
    <div id="imagediv2" class='custom_img'>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">
    </div>
    <div id="imagediv3" class='custom_img'>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```